# What is the bandwidth of a radar operating at 5 GHz?

Tags: signal-processing, radar

[image]

This is the question I have been working on recently. I am trying to figure out how the time-bandwidth product is calculated.

If anyone can send me any useful links that I can learn from I'd be very thankful. I do not want to receive a solution but some kind of explanation would be better.

This question is from an exam from a previous year and I am only practicing with it so please do not ban it.

[image]

Comment: You won't be "banned" for asking, but your question may be closed for not showing what you have done to try to solve the assignment.  What steps have you taken?  How far did you get? Where did you get stuck?  Show your work.

Comment: To have an idea of what happens ... "calculate" f_start at t=0 ... then f_final at t=tau. How change frequency?

Comment: This is a frequency chirp -- if you have study materials dig into the index or search through the ebook for bandwidth of a chirp.  If you don't have study materials, google for the term.

Comment: Some interesting thing https://www.clear.rice.edu/elec301/Projects01/radar_simulation/process.html